# The function can't be unconditionally invoked

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build a dropdown that is filled with values from the database.

The error happens at

```
items: machineList[index].serienummer((String items)
```

The error I get is:

> The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be null.

I tried to add `items: machineList[index].serienummer!` or `items: machineList[index].serienummer?` and `items: machineList[index].serienummer??` parameters but doesn't seem to solve it. Any help would be great.

This is my dart file

```
class _MachinepageState extends State<Machinepage> {
  _MachinepageState();

  final ApiService api = ApiService();
  late List<Machine> machineList;
  String dropdownvalue  = "";


  @override initState(){
    super.initState();
    _getMachine();
    machineList = [];
  }

  void _getMachine() async{
    machineList = (await ApiService().getMoreMachine(widget.klant.klantId.toString()));
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) => setState(() {}));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Menu'),
          backgroundColor:Colors.deepOrange
      ),
      body: machineList == null || machineList.isEmpty
          ? const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
          : SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget> [
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: machineList == null? 0 : machineList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 25.0),
                        child: DropdownButton(

                          // Initial Value
                          value: machineList[1].serienummer,

                          // Down Arrow Icon
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),

                          // Array list of items
                          items: machineList[index].serienummer((String items) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: items,
                              child: Text(items),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          // After selecting the desired option, it will
                          // change button value to selected value
                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              dropdownvalue = newValue!;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ),
```

My Machinemodel.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart';

List<Machine> welcomeFromJson(String str) => List<Machine>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Machine.fromJson(x)));

String welcomeToJson(List<Machine> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Machine {
  Machine({
    this.serienummerId,
    this.serienummer,
    this.bouwjaar,
    this.urenstand,
    this.locatie,
    this.klantId,
  });

  int? serienummerId;
  String? serienummer;
  String? bouwjaar;
  String? urenstand;
  String? locatie;
  String? klantId;

  factory Machine.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Machine(
    serienummerId: json["SerienummerId"],
    serienummer: json["Serienummer"],
    bouwjaar: json["Bouwjaar"],
    urenstand: json["Urenstand"],
    locatie: json["Locatie"],
    klantId: json["KlantId"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "SerienummerId": serienummerId,
    "Serienummer": serienummer,
    "Bouwjaar": bouwjaar,
    "Urenstand": urenstand,
    "Locatie": locatie,
    "KlantId": klantId,
  };
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you documented what you tried.  For example, did you try `machineList![index].serienummer`....?  Note the bang just after `machineList`

Comment: I eddited the question and showed where i placed the parameters. I also tried to use a bang after the machineList but that didn't seem to solve it. @JonMountjoy

Comment: `items: machineList[index]?.serienummer`

Comment: Have you tried `machineList[index]!.serienummer((String items)` ...     ?

Comment: Those parameters doesn't seem to be solving the issue - sorry for the late reaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you passed the `machineList[1].serienummer` in DropdownButton `value`, I'm assuming that `serienummer` is not a list but some kind of value, i.e., an integer or string.

And you're trying to do this `items: machineList[index].serienummer((String items)` which will not work as `items` will only take lists as value.

So try this this:

```
items: machineList!.map((item) {
  return DropdownMenuItem(
    value: item.serienummer, //or whatever value you want to pass to the item
    child: Text(item.serienummer.toString()),
  );
})!.toList(),
```

Don't forget to put the null and empty check for `machineList` before passing it in DropDownButton `items`

Comment: I see where you are going. The only thing that is giving me an error now is the .map

Comment: I eddited the question and added my machine model

Comment: @Minimumspace my bad, there was mistake from my side. Edited my ans.